# How to fix "There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate"?

Tags: python, android

I am trying to use Kivy on a Mac 10.14.6 to create a Python Android application following the tutorial [HERE](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-kivy-tutorial). When I run the command to build the app

```
python3 -m buildozer -v android debug
```

I see the error

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I have been looking at the pages [HERE](https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/c/RCtgkD5xJ2U), [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801869/buildozer-error-while-compiling-apk-pip-ssl) and [HERE](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/master/docs/source/installation.rst), but the suggested fixes do not work. I neither can install `libssl-dev` via

```
brew install libssl-dev
```

nor suggested commands in the third page work. For the latter I still get the same error.

It also looks like that kivy/buildozer is trying to install Cython again(???) which does not work:

```
[INFO]:    -> running bash -c venv/bin/pip install Cython
           working: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HT...(and 192 more) Exception in thread background thread for pid 83565:
```

So what else can I try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

You have to download the source code for python and compile it with ssl support.

First, you make sure `openssl` is up-to-date

```
brew install openssl
```

Next, you find out the location of `ssl`

```
brew --prefix openssl
```

and use that in the folder where you have the python source code:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
make
make install
```

Then you remove the folder `.buildozer` and try to recreate your application.